# How to make a running excutable delete its own file

Tags: c#, delete-file

For example,

I have an excutable TrashClean.exe running. I want it to delete all files I don't want and also delete itself (TrashClean.exe on hard drive) at last step.

I am wondering if it's possible in C#?

Comment: Have you tried just deleting it with [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)?

Comment: Won't work if the file's still actively in use (which it generally will be). Windows will not let you delete a file that has is in use by another app (or even by itself).

Comment: On Windows it looks like impossible, but not sure. You could copy to a temporary location and then delete from original location. And the TEMP files are deleted once they are 7 days old I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please see [How To Make Your Application Delete Itself Immediately](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/HowToDeleteCurrentProcess.aspx):

> I'm sure you've all said to yourself
>   or someone at the office at one point
>   or another, "`<snort>` You idiot. Don't
>   you know a Windows application can't
>   delete itself? I bet you don't even
>   know how to type high ASCII characters
>   using the ALT key and the number pad,
>   gahhhh.."
>
> Sure, there are ways to have a file
>   delete itself on the next reboot...
>   And you can even resort to an external
>   program or batch file to do the work.
>   But I just came up with a nifty way of
>   doing it without leaving a visible
>   trace that the application ever
>   existed!

Comment: Haha, I know, that's why I come here to ask. Thanks for your link. I will look at it.

Comment: By the way, I really don't know how to type high ASCII characters using the ALT key and the number pad:)