# Delete a program that are running in console of C#

Tags: c#, console

I have create a program that delete a folder. 
Like this :

```
    if (Directory.Exists((System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "My Dir Name"))))
    {
        Directory.Delete(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "My Dir Name"), true);
    }
```

this is alright . But a file that name is "Delete.exe" is in directory of "My Dir Name" [Like my code ]  !  It gave an error, because "Delete.exe" is running  and can't delete .

What can I do to delete,  "Delete.exe"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a file which is locked by another process in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040/how-do-i-delete-a-file-which-is-locked-by-another-process-in-c)

Comment: This is a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245201/how-can-i-make-my-net-application-erase-itself, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305428/self-deletable-application-in-c-sharp-in-one-executable, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303783/how-to-make-a-running-excutable-delete-its-own-file, or possibly even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040/how-do-i-delete-a-file-which-is-locked-by-another-process-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to delete the folder in which your running application is in and therefore delete the program itself? Well, you have a few options. It is interesting to note as well that batch files can delete themselves. So, that also leaves you a few more options:

1. have your C# program copy itself to a temp directory before deleting the folder, and run from there.
2. use a batch file entirely instead of C# - having it do whatever and then delete itself afterwards.
3. have your C# program generate and execute a batch file and then quit - leaving the batch file to clean up after the C# program exits.
4. run a CLI command to delete your program after a specified time:

   - `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > Nul & Del " + Application.ExecutablePath);`
5. you can use [MovFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240%28VS.85%29.aspx) to specify to have your program deleted on next start up.

Most of these answers imply that the running EXE is your own appliation. if it is not, though - #5 will still work. you can schedule it to be deleted the next time the computer starts.